# when loaded image is bigger than div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I worked with JavaScript library SVG.js
User can load image to my page, like that `var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            this.image = draw.image(oFREvent.target.result);
        };`
And I have a following problem. When I load image and put it to my `div` when this `div` is smaller than image, I want to create a scrollbar?
How can I do this? 
I will be very grateful for the help!

Comment: Have you tried to apply `overflow: scroll` on that div?

Comment: Yes I tried, but this didn't help, I coudn't scroll and saw hidden part of image

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't display all the code for us to see properly, here's my take on it.

You have a div and inside the div is the svg image.

You want the image to remain inside the div, even if it means placing a scrollbar for the div.

I would do the following:

CSS:

```
div { overflow: auto; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
```

By placing a fixed width/height for the div, it should contain the image inside the div, anything over it should make the scrollbar appear.

Comment: I did like this, but it didn't help. When the image, I load, is bigger than div I see only part of it, how can I see all image?